# Is there a way to set default tab completions in a linux terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, autocomplete

A single table auto-completes if there is only one option

```
amflare:~$ cd t [tab] est-dir/
amflare:~/test-dir/$
```

Double tab displays all option if there is more then one

```
amflare:~$ cd t [tab][tab]
test-dir/ test-dir2/
amflare:~$ cd t
```

But is were a way to default to a specific option if there is more than one option? Say by triple tabbing?

For example:

```
amflare:~$ cd t [tab][tab][tab] est-dir2/
amflare:~/test-dir2/$
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "default to a specific option" ?  How do you see a sequence of three tabs picking one value as "more specific" than another?

Comment: IDK, I figured it would be a .bashrc setting like an alias but for auto complete. ie 'autocomplete t=test-dir2'.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what shell you use, you can pass options to Tab Completion.

For the `bash` shell, as it says in the [Introduction to Programmable Completion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html):

```
The Bash *complete* and *compgen* builtins make it possible 
for tab completion to recognize partial parameters and options to commands.
```

---